# How to assign value into string base ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

I  have to get value from foreign key based Modal but i have the foreign key is like dynamically changed from modal to modal.
this is my code

```
 def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        data = self.model.objects.filter(pk=queryset)
        fk = self.fk_name + '_id'
        inline_data = self.inline_model.objects.filter(#fk_name=queryset)
#fk_name
```

please help me solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of *dictionary unpacking* with:

```
 def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    data = self.model.objects.filter(pk=queryset)
    fk = self.fk_name + '_id'
    inline_data = self.inline_model.objects.filter(**{fk: queryset})
```

If `fk_name` is thus `foo`, we will call the `.filter(…)` function with `.filter(foo_id=queryset)`.

Normally you can however not filter directly with a `queryset`, since a `QuerySet` is a *collection* of objects, not a single object. We can make use of the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) for that:

```
 def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    data = self.model.objects.filter(pk=queryset)
    fk = f'{self.fk_name}_id__in'
    inline_data = self.inline_model.objects.filter(**{fk: queryset})
```